# detect network status even if it is disconnected for a millisecond shell script

Tags: bash, linux-networking, ping, shell-scripting

I have this shell script which keeps running continously.

```
#!/bin/sh
while true;
 do ping -c1 www.google.com > /dev/null;
done
```

When I disconnect my lan cable this script throws error in the terminal

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

but it takes some time to throw the error.

I want it to throw the error instantly even if I disconnect my lan cable for a few milliseconds and then connect it quickly. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using this statement :

```
ping -q -w 1 -c 1 `ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` > /dev/null && echo ok || echo error
```

This statement pings the default gateway and gives an error even if there is a slightest issue in network

Refer this [answer  for a detailed explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929368/how-to-test-an-internet-connection-with-bash)